# jQuery Bootgrid can't open popover

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

I have a jQuery Bootgrid. In one column I want to apply style for cell content and if click on cell open bootstrap popover. I'm using custom formatter and style was apply successfully but popover not working. What is problem?

```
formatters: {
   "delegate": function (column, row) {
        return "<span class='my_style' data-toggle='popover' data-content='" + row.description + "' data-row-id='" + row.id + "'>" + row.description + "</span>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap do you use?

Comment: Valerii, version of Bootstrap is 3.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed by added the following script:

```
$(function() {
   $("#myTable").on('click.rs.jquery.bootgrid', function(e, columns, row, targer) {
      $("[data-toggle='popover'][data-row-id='" + row.id + "']").popover();
   });
});
```